# Custom entity translation interface

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n, console

I created a new custom entity using drupal console, I enabled translation and all looks ok in code.

The problem is that I don't know how to translate an entity from the admin interface, I don't see any options to do this. I looked through the generated files and I don't see any translation related functionality there.

Am I missing something? Should I build my own admin interface and logic to manage translations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed configuration at admin/config/regional/content-language :|

Comment: Is there any way to make a custom entity fully translatable without the need to manually enable it at that page?